# Host de destino inaccessible Equipos en misma red

Tags: windows, redes

Tengo dos equipos conectador por wifi a la misma red pero desde hace dos días ya no se pueden conectar entres si, tengo MyBusinessPos en un equipo como cliente y no puede acceder.

En el centro de redes y recursos compartidos donde antes aparecía el otro equipo ya no aparece más que el local, los mismos en la otra pc, cuando trato de hacer Ping al otro equipo «ping equipo-pc» me aparece Respuesta desde 192.168.1.105 host de destino inaccesible lo extraño es que efectivamente esa es la ip del otro equipo y el internet en ambas máquinas funciona bien, ambas están configuradas como redes de negocio y en la configuración del uso compartido tiene activada la detección de redes, el compartir impresoras y el uso de carpetas publicas cifrado de 40 o 56bits en ambas si contraseña y administrado por Windows.

El firewall en ambas era desactivado

¿Que podría estar ocurriendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución fue reiniciar el módem ‍♂️

Comment: Tacha la pregunta como resuelta.